# Is there any downside to using $injector.get() to get my dependencies in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

My team wants to move to a style of dependency injection that is closer to the CommonJS/Node JS syntax for out Angular codebase:

```
var myDependency = require('myDependency');
```

I've started using `$injector.get()` directly inside at the top of my functions, so far with no obvious trouble.  That means I've converted this:

```
angular.module('modD', ['modA', 'modB', 'modC'])
.service('serviceD', ['serviceA', 'serviceB', 'serviceC', function(serviceA, serviceB, serviceC) {
  //My code here
}])
```

Into:

```
angular.module('modD', ['modA', 'modB', 'modC'])
.service('serviceD', ['$injector', function($injector) {
  var serviceA = $injector.get('serviceA');
  var serviceB = $injector.get('serviceB');
  var serviceC = $injector.get('serviceC');

  //My code here
}]);
```

Is there something I'm missing.  Does not declaring the required dependencies outside of the function definition cause any sort of performance issues?

Answer (score 1):

**Note: this answer has not been tested.**
After digging into the angular's code, I find this:

```
// in function createInjector
function provider(name, provider_) {
    ...
    if (isFunction(provider_) || isArray(provider_)) {
      provider_ = providerInjector.instantiate(provider_);
    }
    ...
    return providerCache[name + providerSuffix] = provider_;
}
...
function factory(name, factoryFn, enforce) {
    return provider(name, {
      $get: enforce !== false ? enforceReturnValue(name, factoryFn) : factoryFn
    });
}
function service(name, constructor) {
    return factory(name, ['$injector', function($injector) {
        return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
    }]);
}
...
// in function createInternalInjector
function invoke (...){
    ...
  for (i = 0, length = $inject.length; i < length; i++) {
    args.push(
      locals && locals.hasOwnProperty(key)
      ? locals[key]
      : getService(key, serviceName)
    );
  }
    ...
    return fn.apply(self, args);
}
function instantiate(...){
    ...
    var instance = Object.create((isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type).prototype || null);
    var returnedValue = invoke(Type, instance, locals, serviceName);
    return isObject(returnedValue) || isFunction(returnedValue) ? returnedValue : instance;

}
...
return {
    invoke: invoke,
    instantiate: instantiate,
    get: getService,
    annotate: createInjector.$$annotate,
    has: function(name) {
      return providerCache.hasOwnProperty(name + providerSuffix) || cache.hasOwnProperty(name);
    }
};
```

Its calls seems like:

- `service` invoked `factory` invoked `instantiate`
- `factory` invoked `provider` invoked `instantiate`

So I think your questions is equal to **Is calling $injector.get() one by one has the same performance as calling $injector.instantiate() once?**

As the code shows, `instantiate` invoked `invoke` which actually invoked `getService` for each services injected by you. And `$injector.get` is just binding to `getService`.

So the answer to my equal question is **True**.

And the answer to your question is **No, their performance is very close**.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, thank you!

Comment: `serviceD` is a `service`, so `instantiate` is called any way for it, `getService` is called for each dependency. The $injector.get version has one more injection (`$injector`), but that's pretty much all of it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no significant difference between both pieces of code in the case of a service. `$injector.get(...)` call doesn't provide any overhead. But it provides a significant amount of extra characters per dependency.

There is a  difference when the same thing is done with injectables that have local dependencies - controllers and route/state resolvers.

When these dependencies

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', function ($scope, service) { ... });
```

are replaced with `$injector.get(...)`, it will choke on `$scope` - it is local dependency. And with other dependencies being retrieved like that, controller loses its testability. The dependencies cannot be mocked with

```
$controller('SomeCtrl', { service: mockedService });
```

I personally don't see how `$injector.get(...)` may benefit the style of the project (and haven't seen a good style guide that would suggest it).

Node uses `require` function because it works for it, not because it is better or cooler. The alternative would be to pack each Node script into into AMD-like wrappers, which would be painful. Fortunately, we already have wrappers around Angular units!

Comment: So we actually use $i.get(), which adds something like 8 chars per dependency after minimization, not a huge sacrifice in favor of clarity and readability. The reason we want to use this style is not because it's "cool" but because it is way more readable when a given controller or whatever has a lot of dependencies.  The $scope thing is interesting, I'll definitely look into that.  Thank you!

Comment: Readability is subjective, but I consider this syntax much less readable. And as it has been said, it adds inconsistency due to local dependencies, which cannot be treated like that. If you're looking for a way to improve readability for injectables with lot of deps, [`$inject` annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#-inject-property-annotation) is a clear winner (besides the other options - ngInject, ES.next decorators, whatever).

Comment: Really?  $injector annotation seems horrible: if I want to delete a  dependency in a list of 16, I have to scroll down to the bottom if the file, count the position of my dependency (let's say 9th), go back to the top, count the 9th argument off, then delete it in both places.  With the NodeJS way, order of deps doesn't matter and they are all in one place (1 statement = 1 dep), so I just comment out the line and that's it.

Comment: The other benefit of our way is stack traces: when I mess up a dep the old way (say: "$timeou"), the error could be anywhere in the code base, and Angular's error reporting gives me a stack trace with links deep inside the angular lib (so essentially useless). When I do it the $i.get way, the line where I made the spelling oops is clearly referenced in the stack trace, and I can go fix it.

Comment: For zero-maintenance injection annotations a clear winner is [ngInject](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate). The major benefit of $inject is that it is applied to named functions, they are hoisted. It is `Service.$inject = [...]; function Service(...) {...}`. For ES6 I prefer wisely built classes [similar to that](https://git.io/v6ccn), the deps listed in `$inject` just become available as class properties.

Comment: Unit's name is already in stack trace, never had problems with finding failed units. You will hardly find a lot of proponents of this style in Angular community for the reasons listed above, but if this works for your team, good for you then.